# In order to pass pl/sql statements using Oracle Semantic functions in PHP

Tags: php, oracle, function, plsql, semantics

I am developing android application connected to Oracle database using PHP,

and I use PL/SQL statements with semantic technologies provided in Oracle(specifically, SEM_MATCH, SEM_MODELS, SEM_RULEBASES or something like this).

However, it doesn't work properly...the connection works well between android and Oracle, though.

The whole php code is shown below

```
<?php
function db_connect()
{
    $db = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 203.249.105.20)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)))";

    if ($conn=oci_connect("rdfusr", "rdfusr", $db)){
        echo "Successfully connected to Oracle.<br />\n";           
        return $conn;
    } else {
        $err = OCIError();
        echo "Oracle Connect Error " . $err[text];
    }
}
$conn = db_connect();
$stid = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT nm.NAME, nm.FLOOR, nm.ROOM_NUM, nm.PHONENUM, nm.FID FROM
(SELECT z FROM TABLE(SEM_MATCH('{?y :soldIn ?z}',
SEM_Models('shopping_model'),
SEM_Rulebases('owlprime','activity_rb'),
SEM_ALIASES(SEM_ALIAS('','http://www.example.org/space/')),null)) 
WHERE y = 'http://www.example.org/activity/Carbonara') ont,BUSINESSINFO nm
WHERE ont.z = nm.NAME;");
oci_execute($stid);
while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_BOTH))) {
    $output[]=$row;
}
print(json_encode($output));

oci_free_statement($stid);
oci_close($conn);
?>
```

Thanks in advance, and give me any kinds of methods please...

Comment: "it doesn't work properly" is not very helpful.  Please be clear in explaining what happens - or does not happen - including any error messages you get.  We can't run your code, so all we know is what you tell us.

Comment: OK..specifically, the connection works well, but warning messages are shown like this:

Comment: Warning: oci_execute():,
Warning: oci_fetch_array():,
Notice: Undefined variable: output in C:\KebiHome\survey\php\orcl_restaurant1.php on line 53
- line 53 is 'print(json_encode($output));'

Comment: the query statement itself is processed perfectly in the sql developer program.